# Can I change Jekyll's temp directory?

Tags: jekyll

Can I change the directory Jekyll uses for it's temporary building?

I'm using Jekyll on a `gh-pages` branch and when I switch back to my Ember project on `master`, it puts new files in `/tmp`. This causes problems with Jekyll's build, and forces me to delete the dir each time I switch back to `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

You have a few ways of doing this, in your local folder, where `_config.yml` is located (Jekyll site root directory):

**A. Editing _config.yml** to have a destination for site generation:

- In `_config.yml`, add the following:

  `destination: /tmp/jekyll_site/`
- This will tell jekyll you want temporary sites generated in the `/tmp/jekyll_site` folder.

**B. Passing the destination via terminal**

- `jekyll serve -d /tmp/jekyll_site/` 
  OR `jekyll serve -destination /tmp/jekyll_site/`
- This flag will have Jekyll generate files in the specified folder.

More information on the configuration options and flags used by Jekyll can be found [here in the documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/). :)